# What is the Opera Version used for Selenium 3 and where to get the driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can you let me know which version opera is used for selenium 3 and where get the driver?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the Selenium site and google? This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the latest version of Opera[Not Sure]. you can download Opera driver from [here](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases)